# Приложение react не доступно

Tags: reactjs

Установил react, node. Запустил, ура. Но

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view youblogs in the browser.

  http://localhost:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

То есть приложение должно быть доступным по адресу
http://ip:3000

Увы, не находит страницу. В чем может быть дело?

Ранее неоднократно устанавливал приложение по разным папкам, пытался запустить. Ничего не получалось, выяснилось что нод висит на 5000 порту. Страницу отдавал но с кодом 404.

В данный момент удалось установить, но что происходит в процессах. Посмотреть могу, но ничего не пойму что предпринимать. Возможно сейчас запущено 2 приложения. Первый висит на 5000 порту и отдает код 404.

Второе, которое должно быть доступно по адресу
http://ip:3000
Страницу вовсе не находит, что необходимо предпринимать. ЧТобы приложение заработало?

Comment: Выполнил команду npm run build, не помогло. Теперь удалил папку build, не понимаю что делать?

Comment: Не `http://ip:3000`, а именно `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: Да, но устанавливаю приложение не на локальном сервере. На удаленном, необходимо обращаться по ip к серверу

Comment: `"scripts": {
   "start": "(set PORT=3006 || export PORT=3006) && react-scripts start"
  },`

Comment: Приложение запустил на 3006 порту, но оно и на нем недоступно.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно принудительно указывать host не просто как localhost по умолчанию, а как реальный адрес ip `HOST=<ввести ip>` или `HOST=0.0.0.0`, в противном случае может не сработать. И хорошо бы проверить, что порт не заблокирован для обращения извне.

Comment: Как верно прописать строчку так, чтобы и host указать и port?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов судя по всему у вас CRA (create-react-app) приложение? судя по тому что я вижу - вы запускаете dev сборку. но зачем? делайте production сборку, получите сборку, с html + js. дальше эти файлы раздавайте как статику да и все, зачем вам dev-сервер?